# Test for a specific node value in an XML column including potentially empty nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have an XML column in a SQL Server 2008 database with values like the following simplified examples:

**Case 1**

```
<root>
    <child>sometimes text here</child>
    <otherstuff ..... />
</root>
```

**Case 2**

```
<root>
    <child/>
    <otherstuff ..... />
</root>
```

Given a string value, I would like to be able to select rows that have a specific value in the "child" node, including selection of case 2.

So for example, if I have a local variable:

```
declare @queryText nvarchar(MAX)
select @queryText = 'sometimes text here'
```

I can select the row that matches case 1 by:

```
select * from [my_table] 
where [my_xml_column].exist('/root/child[text()=sql:variable("@queryText")]') = 1
```

However, for case 2, where I would expect @queryText = '' or @queryText = NULL to work, neither matches.

As a workaround I can use:

```
select * from [my_table]
where [my_xml_column].value('(/root/child)[1], 'nvarchar(MAX)') = @queryText
```

This works, but it leaves me feeling like I'm missing something and using a dirty workaround to test for existence with .value() rather than .exist()...   Is there a similar expression I can [and should?] use in .exist() to match either specific text or an empty node?  Is there any reason to care beyond readability?  I look forward to my impending facepalm when somebody points out whatever blatantly obvious thing I have missed. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `text()` on an empty element results in NULL not an empty string. So, in both cases passing `@queryText = ''` or `@queryText = NULL` will never equal NULL. Remember that nothing equals NULL, not even NULL.

See below example that illustrates how to use `exist` for populated or empty searches.

```
declare @my_table table (i int, my_xml_column xml)
insert into @my_table
    select 1, '<root><child>sometimes text here</child><otherstuff /></root>' union all
    select 2, '<root><child/><otherstuff/></root>'

declare @queryText varchar(100) = '';

select  *, 
        [using_text()]=[my_xml_column].value('(/root/child/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
        [using_path]=[my_xml_column].value('(/root/child)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from    @my_table

select  *
from    @my_table
where   [my_xml_column].exist('/root/child[.= sql:variable("@queryText")]') = 1
```

Comment: Cue the facepalm! :)  I could have sworn I tried that [.=sql:variable] form, but I guess not.  Works like a charm - thanks!

Comment: How about for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130499/how-to-replace-text-if-it-exists-otherwise-add-text-to-a-xml-node-using-sql